# Odin 4.38 not detecting my GTS5570(froyo)

Tags: samsung

I have a samsung galaxy mini(or pop) running 2.2 froyo. I want to flash custom roms in it. I tried using Odin but it doesnt detect my phone. Any idea what the problem might be? I have searched online but none of the methods work.
 I have kies installed.

Comment: Are you putting the phone into Download mode?

Comment: Yes. I did. I tried starting Odin before and after connecting the phone in download mode. Could me using windows 8 be the reason?

Comment: It's possible that your Kies installation is interfering with Odin.  Try uninstalling Kies and re-installing the stand-alone USB drivers for your phone.

Comment: I seem to be getting a 'Usb device not recognised' error. In the device manager under other devices it shows the yellow triangle over MSM7*27. Does that mean anything?

Comment: Yes, this means the USB drivers for your phone in Download mode are not installed properly.  Uninstall all other Samsung USB drivers from your system, reboot the computer, and try these drivers: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2038555